# Is it possible to use one voltage source for an op-amp?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, negative-voltage

This is a typical to op-amp for a non-inverting amplifier.

I have tried to google this before I asked this question.

Unfortunately, all circuit diagrams seem to require two voltage sources. In real life, most of the time, you only have one battery. How do you get a negative supply  voltage?

[image]

[image: Orginal DataSheet Example]

The full circuit diagram. I am trying to amplify the Colpitts oscillator signal with an op-amp but without success.

[image]

R4 and R5 are used as a voltage divider.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141373/discussion-on-question-by-kile-is-it-possible-to-use-one-voltage-source-for-an-o).

Answer (score 3):

Several ways to create a negative voltage:

1. Add a second power supply or a second battery. Usually this is actually not that expensive, especially if you need high current capability. It's also the simplest way. If you use a custom-designed circuit, why not use a custom-designed power supply that for example has a forward converter creating both positive and negative voltages at the same time? Computer PSUs do this.
2. Virtual ground with voltage divider, op-amp buffer and push-pull BJT pair. Create a voltage divider from two large-value resistors of equal value. This creates a "virtual ground", but the problem is you can't source or sink any current from/to it because the voltage changes then and the resistors would allow only very small currents. Then you need to "amplify" the current handling capability of the voltage. In some cases, putting an operational amplifier as a buffer is enough. If it isn't, you need to create a push-pull pair of transistors to further "amplify" the current handling capability of the op-amp. However, the push-pull pair creates crossover distortion, so you may want to add lots of capacitors and further filter the positive and negative voltages with linear regulators that drop quite a bit of voltage and thus dissipate it as heat. For example if you have a 16V supply, you can realistically halve it to +/- 8 V, and then further filter it with 7805 and 7905 linear regulators to +/- 5 V dual sided supply. I described such a circuit here: [Does this inductance measuring oscillator circuit work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/642364/does-this-inductance-measuring-oscillator-circuit-work) ..in a failed attempt to measure inductance by oscillation.
3. Capacitor pump. In simplest form, it can be a 555 and two silicon diodes plus some capacitors. However, you can't source significant current from this so you may want to buffer the 555 output by a BJT pair for more current handling capability and replace the silicon diodes with Schottky diodes. Note the negative voltage produced by this has lots of ripple, so you definitely need a negative voltage linear regulator, and to make the supply symmetrical, you should probably be using an equivalent positive voltage linear regulator, too. Here's one design without a BJT buffer: https://huhtama.kapsi.fi/ele/index.php?si=kyt06.sis (unfortunately it's described in Finnish)
4. Buck-boost converter. With good control, it can invert your positive voltage to a negative one, at very high energy efficiency, at low ripple, so that you don't need any linear regulators. Wikipedia describes it well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck%E2%80%93boost_converter

Note that if your negative in the input is the ground, option (2) probably won't work since the virtual ground would differ from the true ground. But for PSUs isolated from ground, and for batteries, it will work.

Comment: Could  you please provide circuit diagrams instead of only texts?

Comment: @kile as you have an AC signal, a negative supply to your opamp is not needed. Now you just need to find an opamp with enough bandwidth to get to 4.5 MHz. Or bias up a BC547 to do it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: @Neil_UK Can you draw some diagram for  biasing up a BC547 ? I'll appreciate it if you could tweak my circuit a little bit and make it work

Comment: @kile this was the first hit on google when asking 'bias a npn transistor'.      https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/transistor-biasing.html. If you want more specific help, then we need to know what load you want to drive, ie what impedance, and to what signal level.

Comment: @Neil_UK Did you see my latest circuit diagram? I want to make the oscillator work with  the amplified signal

Comment: @kile Yes, I've seen that diagram. It doesn't show the load you want to drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dual charge pump voltage converters: Eg https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX680-MAX681.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/335509)